# Modales En javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una duda con respecto a los modales en javaScript He hecho uno, pero a al momento a crear otro no me deja abrirlo. Este es mi código, ¿Qué debo hacer para poder implementar lo mismo en los demás modales

1. Este es el Js

```js
    const open= document.getElementById ('open');
    const modal_container= document.getElementById ('modal_container');
    const close= document.getElementById ('close');
    open.addEventListener('click', () => {modal_container.classList.add('show');
    })
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {modal_container.classList.remove('show');
    })
```

Comment: Asegúrate de que los modales y sus elementos internos (botones, campos, etc) tengan valores `id` únicos (no puede existir más de un elemento con el mismo `id`). Saludos

Comment: Cambiar los ID`s

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso me parece que tienes el mismo 'id' para ambos modales, debes asegurarte que los 'id' sean únicos. Por ejemplo, acá tenemos dos funciones que se encargan de encapsular el abrir o cerrar modales, ambas reciben como parametro el id (que debe ser único)

```
let abrirModal = (idModal) => 
{
        let elemento = document.getElementById(idModal);
        elemento.classList.add('show');
};

let cerrarModal = (idModal) => 
{
        let elemento = document.getElementById(idModal);
        elemento.classList.remove('show');
};
```

En el HTML deberías tener algo como esto, fijate que existen dos elementos con diferentes identificadores cada uno

```
<div id="modalUno" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="modalDos" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```